# calculate array values by key

Tags: php, arrays

i have a array  problem can i calculate same integer value.
my example arrays on the bottom please

```
int = -21;
```

---

my first array

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [580] => 13.000000
>     [582] => 8.000000
>     [485] => 7.000000
> )
> ```

and i need is algoritm

```
Array
(
    [580] => 13.000000+int // sum -8
    [582] => 8.000000+(-8) // 0 
    [485] => 7.000000
)
```

after result

```
Array
(
    [580] => 8
    [582] => 0
    [485] => 7.000000
)
```

Comment: Hey Ramil. Unfortunately, it is not clear what you are asking. Consider updating your question to explain the problem more clearly(don't forget to mention what you have tried so far) to help people that might be willing to help.

Comment: For the first key: `13.000000+int` will result in `-8`, but you have it as `8` in the result?

Comment: Array
(
    [580] => -8
    [582] => 0
    [485] => 7.000000
)

Comment: That's not what your question says... it says you want `[580] => 8`, not `-8`. Which is it? If anything, that comment made the question _more_ unclear.

Comment: I get how you got `-8`, but again, you have `[580] => 8` as the expected result in your question. Which is it? `[580] => 8` or `[580] => -8`? I get how you would get `-8` but not `8`. That's where the confusion lies.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  sorry [580] => -8

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that. Anyway, I added an answer how you can get that result (-8, that is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly:

```
$array = [
    580 => 13.000000,
    582 => 8.000000,
    485 => 7.000000,
];

// The initial number to sum
$int = -21;

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    // Add the int number to the current element.
    $array[$key] = $val + $int;

    // Now replace $int with the new sum so we'll use that
    // in the next iteration instead
    $int = $array[$key];
}
```

A shorter version would be:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $int = $array[$key] = $val + $int;
}
```

That will give you:

```
Array
(
    [580] => -8
    [582] => 0
    [485] => 7
)
```

*(and the first value is `-8` as you stated in your comments)*

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/95sIC)

Comment: thanks man i need      $int = $array[$key]; this line

Comment: @RamilHuseynov - If this answer solved you problem, please accept it so others know it's been resolved.

Comment: where resolved button?

Comment: There should be an "accept" button (or rather a check mark) to the left of my answer (under the upvotes). Click on that. You can also read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235